# MySQL PHP insert and update

Tags: php, mysql, database, input

I am a little lost being new to databases. I am trying to create a page/form that, from a link only the admin can see, pulls in that $id's information from the database, displays it so that each field can be updated and saves it back to the database. I also added a form at the bottom of the page to input a new field into the database. For simplicity sake I put them on one page but I can separate them out if needed. My code does not work yet and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
echo "<a href=\"test.html?p=ID{$row["id"]}\">Edit</a><br>";
```

spits out a link to test.html?p=ID(#)
The link part is working perfectly.

Admin page

```
<div><h1 class="pageTitle">Episode List UPDATE</h1></div>
    <?php
// Connect to the database
require 'include/episodelist.db.php';

// Ask the database for the information from the season table BUT how to only get info for the ID?
$query="SELECT * FROM `season` WHERE `id` = $id";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM season");
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();
?> 
<form action="include/epslist.update.php" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Season Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="season_sum" size="50" value="<? echo "$season_num";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Episode Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="eps_num" size="50" value="<? echo "$eps_num";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Temp Episode Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="temp_eps_num" size="50" value="<? echo "$temp_eps_num";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Title: </td><td><input type="text" name="title" size="50" value="<? echo "$title";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description: </td><td><textarea type="text" name="descrip" cols="50" rows="7" value="<? echo "$descrip";?>"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="Submit" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table></form>
<div class="Down10px"></div>
<div><h1 class="pageTitle">Episode List NEW</h1></div>
<form action="include/epslist.new.php" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Season Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="season_sum" size="50" value="<? echo "$season_num";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Episode Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="eps_num" size="50" value="<? echo "$eps_num";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Temp Episode Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="temp_eps_num" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Title: </td><td><input type="text" name="title" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description: </td><td><textarea type="text" name="descrip" cols="50" rows="7"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="Submit" value="New Item">
</td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

epslist.update.php

```
<?php
require "episodelist.db.php";

//Test for user inout
if (!empty($_GET[season_sum])&&
    !empty($_GET[eps_num])&&
    !empty($_GET[temp_eps_num])&&
    !empty($_GET[title])&&
    !empty($_GET[descrip]))

    {
// Im at a lost how to pull in the data just for test.html&=edit(#), check if a user changed it, then if so update that value in the database

    // Trying to redirect the user back to the list once the update is finished
        header("Location:");
?>
```

epslist.new.php **UPDATED**

```
<?php
require "episodelist.db.php";

//Test for user inout
if (!empty($_POST[season_sum])&&
    !empty($_POST[eps_num])&&
    !empty($_POST[temp_eps_num])&&
    !empty($_POST[title])&&
    !empty($_POST[descrip]))

    {
        $season_sum = mysqlclean($_POST,"season_sum",$link);
        $eps_num = mysqlclean($_POST,"eps_num",$link);
        $temp_eps_num = mysqlclean($_POST,"temp_eps_num",$link);
        $title = mysqlclean($_POST,"title",$link);
        //This is a text area cols 50 rows 7
        $descrip = mysqlclean($_POST,"descrip",$link);
        $ID = mysqlclean($_POST,"id",$link);
    }

    if ( ! empty($_POST['ID']))
    $id = (int)$_POST['ID'];
    else $id = 'NULL';

    //Insert new entry
    $query = "INSERT INTO `season` (`ID`, `season_num`, `temp_eps_num`, `esp_num`, `title`, `descrip`) VALUES ({$id}, '{$season_sum}', '{$eps_num}', '{$temp_eps_num}', '{$title}', '{$descrip}')";

    // Trying to rederect the user back to the list once the update is successfully finished
        header("Location: episodelist_superadmin.html");
?>
```

Comment: Please make your question title describe the question, instead of just listing technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question, but I think what you're asking for is some edit to

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `season` WHERE 1";
```

which should be something like

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `season` WHERE `id` = $id";
```

Comment: ill give that a shot, pulling the current information into the form is the first part of the question. Lets see if that solve the first problem :)

Comment: Ok, I guess my first problem is passing the value of the id in the link onto the form page. so `admin.html&=ID{$row['id']}\">Edit</a><br>";` goes to admin.html&=ID1. On the form page I need to pull in the database info that matches ID1 out of the URL string. Unless theres another way to tell the form what database information to pull based on what link a user clicked from the list on the admin page?

Comment: you need to read about HTML forms and using GET and POST. I'm feeling nice so I'll point you. You need your link to look like admin.html?ID=$row['id'] and then you can do $_GET['ID'] in the query.

Comment: But to cover my arse, this is very susceptible to SQL injection attacks and so needs cleaning up

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what everyone else have already mentioned, you send your data as method="POST" but your update page only runs if current values are GET. Start by replacing $_GET to $_POST.

There's a lot of things missing in your code. My honest suggestion is to read up more or start out by trying more simple tasks. At this point you'd get something more made by us then by you if we type in PHP how it all should look like.

**Edit:**

A really neat solution you can do is to reuse epslist.new.php for the update:

```
if ( ! empty($_POST['ID']))
  $id = (int)$_POST['ID'];
else $id = 'NULL';

$query = "INSERT INTO `season` (`ID`, `season_num`, `temp_eps_num`, `esp_num`, `title`, `descrip`) VALUES ({$id}, '{$season_sum}', '{$eps_num}', '{$temp_eps_num}', '{$title}', '{$descrip}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE season_num = VALUES(season_num), temp_eps_num = VALUES(temp_eps_num), esp_num = VALUES(esp_num), title = VALUES(title), descrip = VALUES(descrip)";
```

And add a hidden input which sends the ID if you have one (updating page).

Read more here [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

**2nd Edit:**

Now we're diving deep into mysql here:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO season (ID, season_num, temp_eps_num, esp_num, title, descrip)
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT {$id}, '{$season_sum}', '{$eps_num}', '{$temp_eps_num}', '{$title}', '{$descrip}') AS h
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM season WHERE ID = {$id}) OR {$id} IS NULL
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE season_num = VALUES(season_num), temp_eps_num = VALUES(temp_eps_num), esp_num = VALUES(esp_num), title = VALUES(title), descrip = VALUES(descrip)
";
```

I *think* it works... :P Sorry for maybe confusing you.

Comment: I was hoping I wasn't as far from the mark as I thought. It sounds in my head like a simple task :)

Comment: i have however changed from $_GET to $_POST

Comment: My new.php code however still does not want to function...

Comment: The sql command inside the new.php should be inside brackets aswell.

Comment: Robin I am reading through your code now

Comment: So, your saying I would need only one form, but my ID is set to auto_increment and I don't want the user to be able to set the ID.

Comment: Ok, but if I brake the form into 2 parts. If we look at just the code on the "New" form. The one that injects a new row. It doesnt seem to work. The page just returns a "0" no data is inputted into the database.

Comment: `<?php
require "episodelist.db.php";
//Test for user inout
if (!empty($_POST[season_sum])&&
 !empty($_POST[eps_num])&&
 !empty($_POST[temp_eps_num])&&
 !empty($_POST[title])&&
 !empty($_POST[descrip]))
 {
  $season_sum = mysqlclean($_POST,"season_sum",$link);
  $eps_num = mysqlclean($_POST,"eps_num",$link);
  $temp_eps_num = mysqlclean($_POST,"temp_eps_num",$link);
  $title = mysqlclean($_POST,"title",$link);
  //This is a text area cols 50 rows 7
  $descrip = mysqlclean($_POST,"descrip",$link);
  $ID = mysqlclean($_POST,"id",$link);
 }
 `

Comment: `if ( ! empty($_POST['ID']))
 $id = (int)$_POST['ID'];
 else $id = 'NULL';
 //Insert new entry
 $query = "INSERT INTO `season` (`ID`, `season_num`, `temp_eps_num`, `esp_num`, `title`, `descrip`) VALUES ({$id}, '{$season_sum}', '{$eps_num}', '{$temp_eps_num}', '{$title}', '{$descrip}')";
  header("Location: episodelist_superadmin.html");
?>`

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your question properly, do you want to show a link, and when the link is clicked a new page show with information related to this link id, and after editing it you want to save it in database against this id?

If you want this put a reply then I will give you a code to solve your problem.

Comment: The link is shown next to information pulled from my database. When a user clicks on the link for (example) item 4 he is taken to a form page with all of item 4's information populated inside the correct form fields. He then updates something (example) the price. Hits update, then gets kicked back to the list of all items where it shows the new price for item 4.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed...

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `season` WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM season");
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

You're not actually using the $query variable anywhere in that code (admin page).  Assuming that you set $query as Josh indicated, you'd want it to look like this:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query="SELECT * FROM `season` WHERE `id` = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

Comment: Right, my problem is, pulling in the ID from the URL string, then going to the database and populating all the form field with the correct content based on that ID. (Example) if I go to admin.html?p=ID4 the form should be full of all information from the database under ID4. That way the user can update the information and submit it back to the database.